# What is an index set with square brackets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have come across the following for the first time:

$S$ is the index set with $S \subset [N]$ and $|S| = N_S$, where $N$ is an integer value.

In this context, what do the square brackets mean? Further to this, what is the index set in this situation? Finally, just to clarify, does $N_S$ represent the size of the index set?

Comment: Probably $[N]$ stands for $\{1,\ldots, N\}$. I don't have enough context to say whether $N_S$ is just some other notation for $|S|$ or if the equality $|S|=N_S$ requires some proof.

Comment: Unfortunately, $[N]$ is not a common notation (in the sense it is being used for here). You will have to search your source to see if they define it somewhere. Saying $S$ is an "index set" means there some sequence around (a sequence of numbers, or of sets, or of functions, or of some other type of mathematical objects), and $S$ is a set of the index values. $|S|$ is a common notation for the size of a set $S$, so probably $|S| = N_S$ is actually meant to define the notation $N_S$ as the size of $S$.